# Using OpenStreetMap in Java

Tags: openstreetmap, installation, java

I have a requirement of GIS to be implemented using Java. I have read the developer guide for OpenStreetMap but there is insufficient information for its set-up technically.

I am completely new to GIS.

I seek any help regarding technical set-up of OpenStreetMap as well as information about using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of useful information for developers in the [**OpenStreetMap wiki**](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop). In detail, there's the **Using OpenStreetMap for Development** table which contains links to other specific wiki pages about how to embed OSM maps, deploy a web application using OSM (e.g. using OpenLayers), OSM services, etc. There are also several desktop and online projects under the *Main Projects* paragraph from which you could start.

[image: Using OpenStreetMap for Development]

If you don't have to implement an application from scratch, give **[gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.org)** a try:

- http://blog.gvsig.org/2013/05/30/gvsig-2-0-openstreetmap-tiles/
- http://blog.gvsig.org/2013/06/05/gvsig-2-0-openstreetmap-adding-new-servers/